# How to select items from a CSV file containing IDs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file containing ids, I want to load it and select all items with those ids (all rows of the item table) ; what is the corresponding mysql query?

The csv file looks like this:

```
item_id
62964
62977
18210
56108
62990
...
```

I thought about doing the following:

```sql
-- Step 1: Import the CSV file into a temporary table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_ids (id INT);

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
INTO TABLE temp_ids
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES;

-- Step 2: Retrieve items based on IDs
SELECT i.*
FROM item i
JOIN temp_ids t ON i.id = t.id;

-- Step 3: Remove the temporary table
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_ids;
```

But is there a better way of doing this?
Ideally, I would prefer using a VIEW instead of a TABLE so that I don't have to delete the table afterward ; but it seems not possible.

Comment: 'and select all datasets with those ids' - I'm not clear what you mean by this - do you mean select all rows from the table datasets with those ids or something else.

Comment: Provide a sample of your CSV file content.

Comment: *is there a better way of doing this?* I see at least 3 different methods. 1 - LOAD DATA statement. 2 - LOAD_FILE() function. 3 - CSV engine.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes I mean select everything from the rows with those ids, I edited my question.

Comment: @Akina I added an example csv file, and I am curious about the LOAD_FILE() and CSV engine solutions ; I would be glad if you answer with more details ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    item_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    item_val INT
    );

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(12345, 111),
(18210, 222),
(23456, 333),
(56108, 444),
(62964, 555),
(62970, 666),
(62977, 777),
(62990, 888),
(77777, 999);
```

CSV file (Window style):

```
item_id<CR><LF>
62964<CR><LF>
62977<CR><LF>
18210<CR><LF>
56108<CR><LF>
62990<CR><LF>
```

**1. LOAD DATA**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    item_id INT
    ) ENGINE = Memory;
    
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/csv_data.csv'
INTO TABLE tmp
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

SELECT test.*
FROM test 
JOIN tmp ON test.item_id = tmp.item_id;
```

**2. LOAD_FILE()**

```
SELECT test.*
FROM test 
JOIN (SELECT REPLACE(CAST(LOAD_FILE('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/csv_data.csv') AS CHAR), '\r\n', ',') csv_data) csv
JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('[', TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(csv.csv_data, 'item_id', '')), ']'),
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (rownum FOR ORDINALITY,
                                item_id INT PATH '$')) jsontable ON test.item_id = jsontable.item_id;
```

Both methods produces the next output (there is no ORDER BY, so rows ordering may vary):

```
+---------+----------+
| item_id | item_val |
+---------+----------+
|   18210 |      222 |
|   56108 |      444 |
|   62964 |      555 |
|   62977 |      777 |
|   62990 |      888 |
+---------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```